# React production build shows blank page

Tags: reactjs, webpack, production

I have this problem where my react production build shows a blank page when served with simple node server. I have tried to tackle this problem different ways but cant find a solution to this. Any suggestions how to fix this problem would be much appreciated. 
I am using BrowserRouter as the routing option on client side.

Here is my webpack.common.js code for the production build:

```
const path = require("path");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const outputPath = path.join(__dirname, "dist");
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    main: ["@babel/polyfill", "./src/App.js"]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ["node_modules", "./src"],
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: "css-loader!sass-loader"
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|svg)$/,
        loaders: ["file-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("bundle.css"),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' ? '/' : '/',
      filename: "index.html",
      template: path.join(__dirname, "./public/index.html")
    })
  ],
  devServer: {
    port,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    publicPath: "/"
  }
};
```

Here is the entry for the compiler to run the production build:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

const webpackCommonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common');

module.exports = merge(webpackCommonConfig, {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({ NODE_ENV: 'production' }),
    ],
    devtool: "source-map",
    devServer: {
        compress: true,
    },
});
```

Here is the code for node server serving the application:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express()


app.get(['/bundle.css', '/bundle.css.map'], (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});
    fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname, `../dist/${req.url}`)).pipe(res);
})

app.get(['/bundle.js', '/bundle.js.map'], (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'});
    fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname, `../dist/${req.url}`)).pipe(res);
})
app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(port)
console.log("server started on port " + port)
```

Here is the index.html that is compiled to dist folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height:100%">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.gif">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Zoi</title>
  <link href="bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
  <body style="height:100%">
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: The reason why it's probably blank is because your assets aren't loading properly. Look at the network tab and see if you're getting any errors. Your paths in the build are most likely setup incorrectly.

Comment: I looked at the network tab and everything loads in. Also there are no errors present. Could you elaborate on the paths being setup incorrectly - what should I look into and try to fix ?

Comment: It looks like you're rolling your own build process but `create-react-app` has some good documentation on how to it up with `express` - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment, maybe that's something that could help